# All PHP functions in one class and server issues

Tags: php, memory, mysqli, server, cpu-usage

This is the first time I use PHP OOP in programming a website.

I created one class (in one file), and added all functions under that class. The file has about 30 functions, more than 2000 line of code.
I read many discussions about separating classes in categorized files, almost all of those discussions (as I understood) point to one main benefit; it’s the ease of maintenance of the code.

If this is the only benefit, I really prefer to keep all functions in one class, this is easier for me: I call the class once in the header and then I use its functions with one line or more.
What is really makes me worried, the CPU, memory and other server resources usage.

My question is: Is that okay to use one class/file for all functions, or this will affect the server resource negatively?
Until now, I test the code on the localhost, everything is fine, I am afraid that it be different in the real world.

Comment: You shouldn't experience any trouble with a class that has 30 functions and 2000 lines of code, that's minimal in the grand scheme of things. However, you could still break it down into separate classes and use an autoloader or include all necessary classes from one single "controller" type class, which you include into your application once.

Comment: If its just one file, no big deal.  If its a class, depends on how many instances you'll be instantiating of the class per execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:
 No it will not affect the server-resources negatively. (atleast not enough to care)

To give you some advice:
  - In your implementation you gain nothing by using a class compared to just a bunch of functions.
  - If you are interested in OOP, you are on the right track but do some more research on what an class/object is and how to use it.